# jquery remove specific div within filtered response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-filter

I am making a GET ajax call and it is returning html as data.

I only want to return what is within div#product-detail-response and replace that html with what is within the div.product-detail-info.

That works just fine, but when I am logged into the CMS as an admin, it spits out debugging code at the end of every page. I know I could disable that feature, but I'd like to keep it on and just remove the debugging div from the response.

***the div#debugging-info exists within div#product-detail-response**

```
// this displays the html correctly, but it includes the debugging-info that I want removed
var $response=$(data);
$(".product-detail-info").html($response.filter('#product-detail-response').html());

// I tried adding a remove in different spots of this line without success
$(".product-detail-info").html($response.filter('#product-detail-response').html()).remove("#debugging-info");
```

*I also put a display: none; for .product-detail-info #debugging-info {} and this:

```
$("#debugging-info").hide();
```

after the above code.

Response:

```
<div class="product-detail-info">
   html and all the stuff I want to show up
   <div id="debugging-info">
      this shows debugging info, and I want to remove this div completely
   </div>
</div>
```

My desired response:

```
<div class="product-detail-info">
   html and all the stuff I want to show up
</div>
```

AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/product_detail_ajax/'+entry_id,
    type: 'GET',
    data : {},
    dataType: 'html',
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
        var $response=$(data);
        $(".product-detail-info").html($response.filter('#product-detail-response').html());
        $(".breadcrumb-product-title").text($response.filter('#breadcrumb-product-title').text());
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // console.log('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you split the lines up and after you've appended the content you simply call `$('#debugging-info').remove()` on the line below? this looks like it hasn't been added to the DOM yet before you're trying to remove yet even tho logically it should be so.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand I tried the $('#debugging-info').remove(); below everything else, it did not work.

Comment: hmmn... that's strange when contents get added to the DOM you should just be able to remove them like that... maybe do a `console.log($('#debugging-info').length)` to see what you get, if the output is `0` then the element simply doesn't exist and you'll have to dig deeper, if the length is `1` the element exists and you **should** be able to delete it, going home from work now but will try to keep online meanwhile

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand it returned 1

Comment: If it returns 1 then ill have to do some research myself as Id have no clue what could possibly be causing it now, one last thing could be that there is a duplicate div with the same id which causes the crash

Comment: I think there is an extra closing div being injected in this situation, causing it to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have injected the response `html`in the `dom`, you could hide the debugging info element, as follows:

```
$response = $( data );
$( ".product-detail-info" ).html( $response.html() ).find( "#debugging-info" ).hide();
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnbqsea1/)

Comment: The debugging info div exists within #product-detail-response

Comment: You really need to post an example of "data" and what you expect your page to become basing on that "data". I really don't understand you, sorry

Comment: Updated my answer with a JSFIDDLE

Comment: If you want to simply remove the div from the response you can do this $response.find( "#debugging-info" ).remove(); and the div will be removed from response

Comment: @RiccardoC, I updated your answer to make it a bit more readable. It is advisable to write some explanatory text when your answer consists of code.

Answer (score 2):

you actually ve something like this:

the data returned from your call

```
  var data = "<div class='product-detail-info'>html and all the stuff I want to show up<div id='debugging-info'>this shows debugging info, and I want to remove this div completely</div></div>";
```

and now create a dom obj to manipulate your data

```
  var parsed = $('<div/>').html(data);

  parsed.find("#debugging-info").remove();

  $("#result").append(parsed.html());
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h05o3faf/)